# Syntax error on Upsert PostgreSql while usin an insert into with on conflict

Tags: postgresql, syntax, syntax-error, upsert

I'm looking for help with this little code :

```
INSERT INTO "WU_MatchingUsers"("IDWU_User1", "IDWU_User2", "MatchingScore") VALUES(i, j, random);
                     ON CONFLICT ("IDWU_User1", "IDWU_User2")
                     DO
                        UPDATE SET "MatchingScore" = EXCLUDED."MatchingScore";
```

How can I make if there is already an existing row of the id 1 + id 2 to just only update the matching score ?  This not seems to work since I have this error :

```
ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « ON »
LIGNE 16 :                      ON CONFLICT ("IDWU_User1", "IDWU_User2"...
```

Kind regards !

Comment: There should be no semicolon before the `ON`. It's still part of the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: That's didn't solve the problem ...

Comment: [Sure does for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=635fec030dd91233cd03564af0211372)

Comment: What do you get when you run `select version();`

Comment: I obtain this : ```PostgreSQL 11.10 (Debian 11.10-0+deb10u1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
```

Comment: Then the stray `;` in the middle of the statement **is** the reason.

Comment: I have this error now : 

```ERREUR:  il n'existe aucune contrainte unique ou contrainte d'exclusion correspondant à la spécification ON CONFLICT
CONTEXTE : instruction SQL « INSERT INTO "WU_MatchingUsers"("IDWU_User1", "IDWU_User2", "MatchingScore")
                        VALUES(i, j, random)
                            ON CONFLICT ("IDWU_User1", "IDWU_User2") 
                                DO
                                    UPDATE SET "MatchingScore" = EXCLUDED."MatchingScore" »
fonction PL/pgsql inline_code_block, ligne 15 à instruction SQL```

Comment: That's a completely different error message and means (if my French doesn't fail me) that you do not have a unique constraint on those two columns.